Use relationship in attribute function
I have four tables:
places with columns: id
place_details with columns: id, place _id
photos with columns: id
place_photos with columns: id, place_id, photo_id
Inside the Photo model I have:
class Photo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'photos';

    protected $appends = array(
        'storage_url',
    );

    public function getStorageUrlAttribute()
    {
        $path = 'photos/' . $this->id . '.jpg';
        
        if (Storage::disk('public')->exists($path))
        {
            return Storage::disk('public')->url($path);
        }

        return null;
    }
}

I need to be able to access the Place id in the getStorageUrlAttribute function. How can I do this?
Here is what my PlaceDetail model looks like:
class PlaceDetails extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'place_details';

    protected $with = [
        'photo',
    ];

    public function place(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Place::class);
    }

    public function photo(): HasOneThrough
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
            Photo::class,
            PlacePhoto::class,
            'place_id', // Foreign key on PlacePhoto table
            'id',       // Foreign key on Photo table
            'place_id', // Local key on PlaceDetail table
            'photo_id'  // Local key on PlacePhoto table
        )->where('is_primary', true);
    }

And here is what my Place model looks like:
class Place extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'places';

    protected $with = [
        'details',
    ];

    public function details(): HasOne
    {
        return $this->hasOne(PlaceDetails::class);
    }
}


I think you just have to define the relationship between a photo and a place. So like a hasOneTrough relationship called place() from photo to place via place_photos. Then you can acces $this->place->id in getStorageUrlAttribute().

@Techno Photos can belong to many Places though, so I don't know if that would work?

Oh yeah sure, you can also make it hasManyTrough(tho how can a photo be at many places?) Its up to you to decide which of the places id you want to use ofc, or iterate over all of them
